# Covid vaccine requirement waiver for travel to US

Tags: usa, covid-19

My mom wants to travel to USA as a tourist. She has a medical contraindication to receiving a covid vaccine. I wonder how to apply for a waiver to covid vaccine requirement and if it is even possible to obtain one.

Answer (score 8):

The [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/international-travel-during-covid19.html) site says (my emphasis)

> Non-U.S. citizen, non-U.S. immigrants: You must show proof of being
> fully vaccinated with the primary series of an accepted COVID-19
> vaccine before you board your flight to the United States. **Only
> limited exceptions apply**.

If you scroll down to near the bottom, there is a link to the exceptions in this paragraph.

> Air Travel: All non-U.S. citizen, non-U.S. immigrants traveling to the
> United States by air are required to show proof of being fully
> vaccinated against COVID-19. Only limited [exceptions](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html#noncitizen) apply. Learn more
> about this requirement and accepted vaccines.

That link has this to say about valid exceptions:

> Persons with documented medical contraindications to receiving a
> COVID-19 vaccine

So technically your mother can travel if she receives an exemption.  It goes on to say

> If you travel by air to the United States under one of these
> exceptions, you will be required to attest that you are excepted from
> the requirement to present Proof of Being Fully Vaccinated Against
> COVID-19 based on one of the exceptions listed above

<strike>However I have no clue as to how the airlines will respond to this, or even what constitutes proof.</strike>

Down at the bottom of that last page is a FAQ on exceptions.

> **What do I need to show if I have a medical contraindication to receiving a COIVID-19 vaccine?**
>
> You must show a letter from a licensed physician documenting the
> medical contraindication to the airline or aircraft operator before
> boarding a flight to the United States.
>
> The letter
>
> - Must be signed and dated on official letterhead that contains
>   contact information (name, address, and phone number) of a licensed
>   healthcare provider.
> - Must clearly state that you have a medical contraindication to
>   receiving a COVID-19 vaccine. The name of the COVID-19 vaccine product
>   and the medical condition must both be listed.
>
>   - Medical contraindications to COVID-19 vaccination include immediate or severe allergic reaction (e.g., anaphylaxis) after a
>     previous dose or component of a COVID-19 vaccine or known allergy to a
>     component of a COVID-19 vaccine.
> - Must have sufficient personally identifiable information (full
>   name plus at least one other identifier such as date of birth or
>   passport number) to confirm that the letter matches with your passport
>   or other travel information.
>
> If your letter is in a language other than English, check with your
> airlines or aircraft operator to find out if translation of the letter
> is necessary for their review.